# Give an example of a ring of cardinality 8 such that there are exactly 6 zero divisors

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to solve this exercise:

> Give an example of a ring of cardinality 8 such that there are exactly 6 zero divisors

My first thought was that it could've been $Z_8$ but the only zero divisors are $$a \in Z:\ GCD(a, 8) > 1$$
And those are $[2], [4], [6]$, those are only 3 and I need exactly 6.

Is my way of thinking correct for this exercise? What could be a "working" example? Thank you!

Comment: in [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ZeroDivisor.html) a zero divisor is different from 0. in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_divisor) 0 is a zero divisor. But when I look at your example it  seems that you use the definition of [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ZeroDivisor.html). Are you sure that 0 is no zero divisor?

Comment: Given $(A, +, *)$ ring, $a \in A - \{0\}$ is a zero divisor if and only if $\exists \ b \in A - \{0\}$ such that $a*b=b*a=0_A$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$? This has 8 elements:

$$(0,0,0),(1,1,1),(0,1,1),(0,0,1),(1,1,0),(1,0,0),(1,0,1),(0,1,0)  $$

Every element other then $(0,0,0)$ and $(1,1,1)$ can be killed by an other element. Just multiply it with the element that has zeros where the original element has ones. This should do it.

Comment: in [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ZeroDivisor.html) a zero divisor is different from 0. in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_divisor) 0 is a zero divisor. But when I look at the example of the OP st seems that she uses the definition of [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ZeroDivisor.html)

Comment: You are right. I edited the answer and replaced the example by another one.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried your previous example $Z_2 \ \times \ Z_4$ and it has exactly 5 zero divisors, right?

Comment: Yep, if $0$ is not a valid answer than there are exactly $5$ zero divisors.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help! Have a great day :)

Comment: You're welcome. You too. :)